# Replace ordered columns after first occurrence of value

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to recode all 0 columns below to be 1 whenever previous year columns are 1.

Begin with this dataframe:

```
library(tibble); library(dplyr)

(df <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3),
       `1997` = c(1,0,0), 
       `1998` = c(0,1,0), 
       `1999` = c(0,0,1)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id `1997` `1998` `1999`
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1      1      0      0
#> 2     2      0      1      0
#> 3     3      0      0      1
```

End with this dataframe:

```
tibble(id = c(1,2,3),
       `1997` = c(1,0,0), 
       `1998` = c(1,1,0), 
       `1999` = c(1,1,1))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      id `1997` `1998` `1999`
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1      1      1      1
#> 2     2      0      1      1
#> 3     3      0      0      1
```

Is there a way to do this with `dplyr` and the `mutate_at`/`mutate_if` function?

I need a way to select just the year columns, find the smallest year column that has a value of 1, and based on that result mutate all larger year columns.

```
# Method that uses dplyr::mutate_at?
# df %>% mutate_at(vars(`1997`:`1999`), funs(replace(., . == 0 & previousColumnVar == 1, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = +(cumsum(value) >= 1)) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Which gives:

```
## A tibble: 3 x 4
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id `1997` `1998` `1999`
#  <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1     1      1      1      1
#2     2      0      1      1
#3     3      0      0      1
```

Comment: This look like it will work great thanks. Can I bother you to explain the use for the `+` syntax?

Comment: @ddheart It converts  `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0`

Comment: I have an additional special case where I have to use a column `StartYear` that defines a specific place to count from rather than the present method of just taking the lowest year. Is there an obvious way to reproduce what you've written using specific cases, where the dataframe is instead  `(df <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3),
                '1997' = c(1,0,0), 
                '1998' = c(0,1,0), 
                '1999' = c(0,0,1),
                StartYear = c('1997', '1998', '1999')))` ? (backticks swapped w/ quotes for SO markdown)

Comment: @ddheart Same logic applies: `df %>% gather(key, value, -id, -StartYear) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value = +(key >= StartYear)) %>% spread(key, value)`